# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes after dormant period

Tags: dell, 19.10

Ubuntu 19.10, Dell Inspirion 5379

After a dormant period (~30 minutes) my computer cannot connect to my network. I know the network is operating because every other device in the house works. Settings > Wifi shows that it is connected, usually all of the other programs on my laptop respond. When I click on a browser link or enter a command in the Terminal it searches forever unless I force the process to stop. I thought this was a wifi problem but sometimes even the laptop, programs and my bluetooth mouse are frozen and I have to force a cold boot, it will not un-freeze by itself. This has become a daily event. Can anyone tell me what to check or what I should look for?

Here are my results suggested by other posts with a similar problem, I have only a vague idea of what they mean:

```
qpackard@:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.3Gi       4.6Gi       325Mi       1.5Gi       5.5Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

qpackard@:~$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness
[sudo] password for qpackard: 
vm.swappiness = 60

qpackard@:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1.12.0
```

Comment: have you looked at `sudo journalctl` right before and then after it happens? Perhaps there is an event in the logs that needs to be corrected

Comment: `journalctl --since="-35 minutes"` and `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will help.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I will reboot now, run the journal command, and after the computer freezes I will reboot and run the command again. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: It happened again. This time the log started with some interesting information but I cannot figure out what triggered it. Here are the first few lines: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1575928214.9317] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
gnome-shell[1597]: Removing a network device that was not added

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem was related to wifi and power, that is, after a short while the wifi automatically disconnected and the computer became stuck while continuously trying to re-connect to wifi.
I have solved this, or at least postponed the disconnect time to an hour or two by turning off the auto-suspend feature in Ubuntu: Settings > Power > Power Saving > Automatic Suspend > Off